# Trouble linking php to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Trying to link my php form to my database but the values aren't being identified. An error message says:

Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4.

It also says unidentified variable for all the values.

Can anyone find a fault?

```
<?php
$dbAddress='localhost';
$dbUsername='root';
$dbPassword='xxxxxxxx';
$dbDatabasename='Studentanswers'
?>


<?php

$link = mysql_connect($dbAddress, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);

if (!$link) {
die("Could not connect");
};

print "Connected to the database server";

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbDatabasename, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die("Could not use the database");
};

print "selected a DB";

$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO $dbDatabasename (`faculty`, `date`, `modulecode`, `moduletitle`, `school`, `modulebookcontent`,
`moduleorganisation`, `lrcmaterials`, `moduledifficulty`, `modulesimilarity`, `contentinteresting`, `previousknowledge`,
`understoodassessmentrequirements`, `assessmentmethod`, `markedwork`, `moduleleader`, `ML_interestforsubject`, `ML_contentclear`, 
`ML_appropriateteachingpace`, `ML_reachableforadvice`, `ML_helpfulfeedback`, `lecturer1`, `L1_interestforsubject`, 
`L1_contentclear`, `L1_appropriateteachingpace`, `L1_reachableforadvice`, `L1_helpfulfeedback`, `lecturer2`, `L2_interestforsubject`, `L2_contentclear`,
`L2_appropriateteachingpace`, `L2_reachableforadvice`, `L2_helpfulfeedback`, `hoursofindependentstudy`, `overallattendance`,
`bestfeaturesofmodule`, `improvemodule`) 
VALUES (`$faculty`, `$date`, `$modulecode`, `$moduletitle`, `$school`, `$modulebookcontent`, `$moduleorganisation`, `$lrcmaterials`, `$moduledifficulty`, 
`$modulesimilarity`, `$contentinteresting`, `$previousknowledge`, `$understoodassessmentrequirements`, `$assessmentmethod`, `$markedwork', `$moduleleader`, 
`$ML_interestforsubject`, `$ML_contentclear`, `$ML_appropriateteachingpace`, `$ML_reachableforadvice`, `$ML_helpfulfeedback`, `$lecturer1`, `$L1_interestforsubject`, 
`$L1_contentclear`, `$L1_appropriateteachingpace`, `$L1_reachableforadvice`,`$L1_helpfulfeedback`, `$lecturer2`, `$L2_interestforsubject`, `$L2_contentclear`, 
`$L2_appropriateteachingpace`, `$L2_reachableforadvice`, `$L2_helpfulfeedback`, `$hoursofindependentstudy`, `$overallattendance`, `$bestfeaturesofmodule`, `$improvemodule`)");

if (!$result) {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

print "run a query against the DB";

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Where are you getting those values for the SQL query?  There's a *very good chance* that you're neglecting to sanitize user input and the error is a result of a SQL injection vulnerability being unintentionally realized.  Other than that, at least formatting the code to be human-readable will help identify syntax errors.

Comment: replace backticks to qoutes

Comment: Are the PHP variables `$faculty`, `$date`, `$modulecode`, etc. being defined anywhere in your PHP code?  If they're not being defined, they're not going to make it into your SQL query.

Comment: Sidenote: Add a semi-colon at the end of `$dbDatabasename='Studentanswers'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few comments:

1. You need to quote your values with single or double quotes (no backticks): `VALUES ('$faculty', '$date' ...,`
2. You should switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and to avoid potential sql injection problems.
3. Your variables seem to be undefined. If you rely on `register_globals`, don't, it is dangerous and deprecated.

Comment: what are register_globals? sorry.

Comment: @taniakeira With `register_globals` on you can access posted variables like `$_POST['faculty']` or `$_GET['faculty']` as just `$faculty`, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 1):

When you use variables, you should do this:

```
"INSERT INTO `".$dbDatabasename."` ..
VALUES ('".$faculty."', '".$date."', ..
```

As you understand, you must seperate variables like this: ".$variable."

Comment: you can use vars in strings with double qoutes perfectly 
try it: `echo "Hello $name";`

Comment: But I think it is stupid thing to get used to. Better to learn like I showed. Later no problems with single qoutes.

Comment: that would be your opinion, in complex statements it improves readability when you do it with double qoutes

Comment: please change the back qoutes to single qoutes in your code example too : `'".$dbDatabasename."'`

Comment: You don't need to use back quotes with values but it's good to use with table name.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed a typing error near **$markedwork**

```
   <?php
    $dbAddress='localhost';
    $dbUsername='root';
    $dbPassword='xxxxxxxx';
    $dbDatabasename='Studentanswers'
    ?>


    <?php

    $link = mysql_connect($dbAddress, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);

    if (!$link) {
    die("Could not connect");
    };

    print "Connected to the database server";

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbDatabasename, $link);
    if (!$db_selected) {
    die("Could not use the database");
    };

    print "selected a DB";

    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO $dbDatabasename (`faculty`, `date`, `modulecode`, `moduletitle`, `school`, `modulebookcontent`,
    `moduleorganisation`, `lrcmaterials`, `moduledifficulty`, `modulesimilarity`, `contentinteresting`, `previousknowledge`,
    `understoodassessmentrequirements`, `assessmentmethod`, `markedwork`, `moduleleader`, `ML_interestforsubject`, `ML_contentclear`, 
    `ML_appropriateteachingpace`, `ML_reachableforadvice`, `ML_helpfulfeedback`, `lecturer1`, `L1_interestforsubject`, 
    `L1_contentclear`, `L1_appropriateteachingpace`, `L1_reachableforadvice`, `L1_helpfulfeedback`, `lecturer2`, `L2_interestforsubject`, `L2_contentclear`,
    `L2_appropriateteachingpace`, `L2_reachableforadvice`, `L2_helpfulfeedback`, `hoursofindependentstudy`, `overallattendance`,
    `bestfeaturesofmodule`, `improvemodule`) 
    VALUES (`$faculty`, `$date`, `$modulecode`, `$moduletitle`, `$school`, `$modulebookcontent`, `$moduleorganisation`, `$lrcmaterials`, `$moduledifficulty`, 
    `$modulesimilarity`, `$contentinteresting`, `$previousknowledge`, `$understoodassessmentrequirements`, `$assessmentmethod`, `$markedwork`, `$moduleleader`, 
    `$ML_interestforsubject`, `$ML_contentclear`, `$ML_appropriateteachingpace`, `$ML_reachableforadvice`, `$ML_helpfulfeedback`, `$lecturer1`, `$L1_interestforsubject`, 
    `$L1_contentclear`, `$L1_appropriateteachingpace`, `$L1_reachableforadvice`,`$L1_helpfulfeedback`, `$lecturer2`, `$L2_interestforsubject`, `$L2_contentclear`, 
    `$L2_appropriateteachingpace`, `$L2_reachableforadvice`, `$L2_helpfulfeedback`, `$hoursofindependentstudy`, `$overallattendance`, `$bestfeaturesofmodule`, `$improvemodule`)");

    if (!$result) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    print "run a query against the DB";

    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```